# After updating my Wordpress site manually(Using FTP), on my wordpress dashboard I still get a "An updated version of WordPress is available."

Tags: wordpress

After updating my Wordpress site manually (Using FTP), at my wordpress dashboard I still get a "An updated version of WordPress is available." As seen in the image. Please how can I get rid of it. Thank you

[image]

Comment: As you have updated WordPress manually which result in prevention of necessary metas related to update process are not store in database. It is something like synchornizing database.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the version number of your WordPress website by accessing your site via FTP and checking the file **wp-includes/version.php**. At the beginning of that file, you will see the real version number of the website, for example:

```
$wp_version = ‘5.6.2’
```

You can also check the releases category archive for what is the latest version.

https://wordpress.org/news/category/releases/